# When I moved work item in TFS board the work item assigned to me

Tags: tfs

I encountered in strange behavior in the sprint board, when I move a task to another state (e.g. From "Active" to "In Progress") the task "assigned to" field became to my user.

I check again and again the work item XML and we don't have a rule regarding the Assigned To field that should do this behavior.

Is a bug? what can we do to make is not happen?

We use TFS 2018 Update 3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep examination we succeeded to find the issue source.

In the top right of the board you can filter the board by user, when the value was my user the work item changed to my user(when I moved the state), when I switched it "All" the behavior became to be normal.

[image]

By the way, in Azure DevOps this behavior doesn't exist (even if the filter is in my user the work item not be changed).